# 1. how to autocomplete and autosuggestion dropdown list for the dynamic range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to develop a code which can help me to create a dropdown list with auto-suggestion and auto-completion with the option being filtered in the list.
eg. if it type 'a' then the dropdown list should show the result of all the options containing 'a' and once i type 'ab', the dropdown option should filter out automatically. The data is been fetched from the database and hence the range has to be dynamic and should be auto-updated in the dropdown list using VBA.

I have tried several code available on the web but something or the other is missing and have been stuck with the issue since long. The functionality works with the excel formulas but i need it via VBA.

```
If target.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
   ' Added this to auto select all text when activating the combox box.
xCombox.SetFocus

With xCombox
    .ListFillRange = vbNullString
    .LinkedCell = vbNullString
    .Visible = False
End With


Dim xStr As String
Dim xArr


If target.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
    ' The target cell contains Data Validation.

    target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False


    ' Cancel the "SelectionChange" event.
 Dim Cancel As Boolean
    Cancel = True


    xStr = target.Validation.Formula1
    xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)

    If xStr = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    With xCombox
        .Visible = True
        .Left = target.Left
        .Top = target.Top
        .Width = target.Width + 5
        .Height = target.Height + 5
        .ListFillRange = xStr

        If .ListFillRange = vbNullString Then
            xArr = Split(xStr, ",")
            TempCombo.List = xArr
        End If
         .LinkedCell = target.Address

    End With

    xCombox.Activate
    Me.TempCombo.DropDown
```

Any kind of suggestion and solutions is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Can you provide us with some of the code you are trying to use and what you have attempted thus far?

Comment: In my project, I have a userform that holds a textbox and a listbox (the latter could alternatively be a combobox). I use a [KeyUp event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/keydown-keyup-eventsevent) for the textbox to see if the user typed anything in the box, and then re-run the sql query that populates the combobox below it, based on the filter from the textbox. Perhaps this could set you in the right direction?

Comment: I tried using combo box also, by changing the properties of the combobox using the excel formula. But it doesn't work. @TimStack

Comment: Actually i'm not aware of the author of the code so i don't know if it will be a good idea to share the code still i have added the code in the post. @rohrl77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OP has mentioned trying to use a ComboBox to display the filtered data...:

In my project, I have both a `textbox` and a `listbox` (the latter could alternatively be a `combobox`. The textbox is open for the user to type a filter in, whereas the listbox displays the items filtered, which were imported from the database.

The textbox (in this case named `machbox`) has a [KeyUp event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/keydown-keyup-eventsevent) which in turn updates the listbox:

```
Private Sub machbox_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

'If what has been typed is a number / Delete / Backspace
If KeyCode = vbKeyBack Or KeyCode = vbKeyDelete Or (47 < KeyCode And KeyCode < 58) Or KeyCode Like vbKeyNumpad & "*" Then
    If Len(Me.machbox.Value) > 3 Then nlist 'prevents the query from firing when the filter is too broad
End If
End Sub
```

Then the sub that populates the listbox:

```
Sub nlist

'Set F as the filter, which is the value of the listbox
F = machbox.Value

'I have ommited the code that connects to the DB

'Clear the listbox so it won't keep the records from the previous filter
Me.ListBox1.Clear

'Execute the query and parse the records to the listbox
Set rs = cnn.Execute("Select * From Table Where Code = '" & F & "'") 'example query
If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then
   Do While Not rs.EOF
      Me.ListBox1.AddItem (rs.Fields(0).Value)
      rs.MoveNext
   Loop
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I'm still trying to figure out your code. 
In my case, the values selected in the dropdown list acts as the variable and are included in the sql query. And can't we just use a combobox, select the dynamic range and a code for updating the dropdown and suggestion for the dropdown. I dont' know if I'm making any sense to you. But my mind is kinda freeze. ;) @TimStack

Comment: I don't think I quite follow. The way I understand is that you want to use a dropdown box which has to only show values based on what you typed in. That is what I have constructed, only that I created a separate textbox for the filter, and the options displayed in the listbox come straight from a DB because "_The data is been fetched from the database and hence the range has to be dynamic and should be auto-updated in the dropdown list using VBA_". I have edited explanatory comments to my code

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @TimStack.  :)

Comment: No problem! In the case this helped solving your problem, please don't forget to accept the answer.